# Is raw string literal null terminated like normal string literal?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, string-literals, rawstring

I know that a string literal is always null terminated, even `""` has a length of 1.

Is it the same case with raw string literal, ex: does `R"()"` has a length of 1?

Comment: You can `std::cout << sizeof(R"()") << '\n';` to see for yourself ;-).

Comment: Or check it in the reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: Thanks TonyDelroy, churill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raw string literals are just normal C strings that ignore escapes, which means they're still null-terminated. It's not like `"foo"s`, which is an actual c++ `std::string`, which isn't necessarily null-terminated.

Comment: _"not like "foo"s, which is an actual c++ string, which isn't null-terminated."_ - `std::string`s are NUL terminated (guaranteed since C++11 if I recall correctly, when `.data()` and `.c_str()` became functional equivalents).

Comment: @TonyDelroy It's a little tricky. "Null terminated" usually means two things: "theres a 0 byte at the end, and that there's no 0 byte anywhere else, so the end of the string can be found by searching for a null. AKA: The null terminates the string"  `std::string` has a 0 byte at the end, but can also contain 0s throughout, so the assumption that you can find the end by searching for 0 doesn't hold. Definitions get a little wobbly here.

Comment: You may be thinking of `"foo"sv`, which, being a `std::string_view`, isn't required to be `NUL`-terminated. `"foo"s` is guaranteed to store a `NUL` after the last character (it could have `NUL`s earlier on, so as Mooing Duck notes, it's not "terminated" when you see a `NUL`, but it's guaranteed to have *at least* one at the end).

Comment: @t.niese Right, I guess, in practice they don't append it just when calling `c_str`, but always carry the terminator around. But yes, basically that answer is correct.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Plain old C-style string literals are described as `NUL`-terminated too, and they [can have embedded `NUL`s in them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34990187/364696). Sure, C-string oriented APIs won't see anything past the first embedded `NUL`, so it's fairly useless normally, but that doesn't mean the literal can't contain them. C++ strings know their size, so the terminal `NUL` doesn't exist to *define* where they terminate, but they always terminate with a `NUL`. Point is,`std::string` is `NUL`-terminated just like C string literals.

Comment: @churill "*in practice they don't append it just when calling `c_str`*" - prior to C++11, that was allowed, but no implementation actually did it. But since C++11, that is no longer possible. "*but always carry the terminator around*" - yes, that has generally the common case, even before C++11 required it.